# Button not visible when opening Form as Child in Panel (WinForms C#)

Tags: c#, winforms-interop

I'm working on a WinForms application in C# and facing an issue with a button's visibility. My application has a main form `MainForm` which opens other forms as child forms inside a panel. One of these child forms is `UserForm`, which contains a button `btnAdd`.

When I run `UserForm` independently, everything works fine and `btnAdd` is visible and functional. However, when I open `UserForm` as a child form within `MainForm`'s panel, `btnAdd` becomes invisible or inaccessible.

Here's how I'm opening child forms in `MainForm`:

```
private void openChildForm(Form childForm)
{
    if (activeForm != null)
        activeForm.Close();
    activeForm = childForm;
    childForm.TopLevel = false;
    childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panelMain.Controls.Add(childForm);
    panelMain.Tag = childForm;
    childForm.BringToFront();
    childForm.Show();
}
```

And here's the `btnAdd_Click` event in `UserForm`:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserModuleForm userModule = new UserModuleForm();
    userModule.btnSave.Enabled = true;
    userModule.btnClear.Enabled = false;
    userModule.ShowDialog();
    LoadUser();
}
```

I've tried the following:

- Checked the `btnAdd` properties (Visible is set to True).
- Made sure `btnAdd` is not being overlapped by other controls.
- Used breakpoints to see if something is changing `btnAdd`'s visibility state.

I suspect the issue might be related to how the form is being docked or displayed in the panel, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any suggestions on what might be causing this and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably not related to the issue, but where you do `activeForm.Close();` I think you would also need to do something like `panelMain.Controls.Remove(activeForm);`.